# How can I parameterize a Firebase API call within a closure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase cloud functions to sync my Firestore db to a 3rd party db. Since my cloud functions use calls to a 3rd party API, I want to parameterize the api call as an input to use dependency injection while testing. The only way I can think of doing this is basically putting the cloud function within a regular function, i.e.,:

```
function foo(apiCall = api) {
  exports.bar = 
      functions.firestore.document(doc_name).onCreate(snapshot => apiCall(snapshot));
  return exports.bar
}
foo();
```

When I try to deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions` I'm told firebase doesn't see the functions as existing in the local source code.

I've additionally tried something like to no effect:

```
function foo(apiCall = api) {
  return functions.firestore.document(doc_name).onCreate(snapshot => apiCall(snapshot));
}
exports.bar = foo();
```

When I put `exports.bar` outside of the function, it deploys fine.

This is my first time using Firebase so I'm not too familiar with the syntax and such, but I don't know why wrapping the cloud function with a regular function wouldn't work - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  The exports must be defined statically at the top level of index.js so that the CLI can find and deploy them.  They can't be exported dynamically through a function.